# Is there a way to trace html tags if it has a specific php function?

Tags: php, html

I would like to know if it's possible to execute this, for example:

if h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 has a php function like this:

```
<h1 class="mar-0"><?= $application->langWebService("Mehr Service"); ?></h1>
```

then there should be a respond of a boolean "true"

if the headings has no php function like this:

```
<h1>There is no php function here...</h1>
```

then it there is an update that there is a certain php function missing, or return false or maybe it will generate a php function if it is not present, is this possible?

Comment: You should know there is a PHP function call since you type it. Where do you want to check it? Client-side or server-side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for and what you are trying to achieve.  Why do you need it to have a function in the header?

Comment: I have a project, and is big now, and that function is suppose to translate text from german to english. I just want to add that function to every headings that I missed.

Comment: @Cid In the server-side